# Truffle Assert with Truffle Beta

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript, truffle-assertions

I just updated to Solidity 5 and Truffle Beta and am testing my contracts in JavaScript.

I am trying to test my constructor events and want to use as per truffle-assertions [documentation](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-assertions) :

> truffle-assertions offers the possibility to create a transaction
>   result object from a contract instance and a transaction hash, which
>   can then be used in the other functions that the library offers.
>
> ```
> let contractInstance = await Contract.new(); let result = await
> truffleAssert.createTransactionResult(contractInstance,
> contractInstance.transactionHash);
>
> truffleAssert.eventEmitted(result, 'TestEvent');
> ```

When I run the following line of code but applied to my contract and then check the event it doesn't work anymore (but did fine with the previous version):

```
let result = await truffleAssert.createTransactionResult(contractInst, contractInst.transactionHash);
truffleAssert.eventEmitted(result, 'Started');
```

Here is the following error that is returned in the Terminal when I run **truffle test**:

```
AssertionError: Event of type ContractStarted was not emitted
    No events emitted in tx 0x8ed0e7489....
```

I **console.log(result)** and it does return a transaction hash. I'm not sure what I should do to get it to work and wonder if it might be due to truffle-assertions **createTransactionResult** not having been updated for the latest version? Or am I missing a line of code that I now need with the newer version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for using my `truffle-assertions` library. Apparently this was caused by a bug in the function. I fixed the bug, and published a new version 0.7.1 to npm that you can use. Using this version should fix your issue.

If there are any remaining issues, please [open an issue on the repository](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-assertions/issues).